# Gis Exam Books and Exam Study Material

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcgis-10.0

Do any one have books or study material for ARC GIS Desktop Associate , i can also buy used books .

Answer (score 2):

The **[ArcGIS Desktop Associate 10.0](http://www.esri.com/training/main/certification/desktopAssociate)** certification is already quite specific about what it seeks to test.

If the suggestions offered on its **Preparation Resources** tab are unsuitable or insufficient then I would recommend that you seek terms from its **Skills Measured** tab for searches against this site and the **[ArcGIS Online Help](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.2/)**.

For example, "arcgis supported data formats" yields many hits from both sites:

- http://resources.arcgis.com/search/?do=search&start=0&filter=0&lg=en&product=&version=10.2&collection=help-general&q=arcgis+supported+data+formats
- https://gis.stackexchange.com/search?q=arcgis+supported+data+formats

Answer (score 1):

Since you are looking for a book, there is one published by Esri Press recently:

[Esri ArcGIS Desktop Associate Certification Study Guide](http://esripress.esri.com/display/index.cfm?fuseaction=display&websiteID=236)

[image]